# RN ScrollView reduce amount of swipe needed

Tags: react-native, mobile, scrollview

I'm using a ScrollView for my app onboarding (horizontal scrolling/swiping).

How can I reduce the amount of swipe needed to move to the next page? (with pagingEnabled).

I want the user to be able to scroll with shorter swipe lengths rather than having to drag a lot to one side or the other.

And if I don't use pagingEnabled and instead use snapToInterval/Alignment and decelerationRate, I have this issue where the user can scroll multiple pages at once.